# powershell script create custom columns to screen output

Tags: powershell, format, output

I need to create custom columns to the output of my script in powershell.

```
dc55   (UTC-04:00) Santiago 4/26/2017 11:34:42 AM
DC10   (UTC-04:00) Santiago 4/26/2017 11:34:43 AM
DC11   (UTC-04:00) Santiago 4/26/2017 11:34:44 AM
DHCP10 (UTC-04:00) Santiago 4/26/2017 11:34:44 AM
DHCP11 (UTC-04:00) Santiago 4/26/2017 11:34:45 AM
```

so for example i need to format the output in this way

```
Server       TimeZone         Date and Time
-----        --------         --------------
dc55   (UTC-04:00) Santiago 4/26/2017 11:34:42 AM
DC10   (UTC-04:00) Santiago 4/26/2017 11:34:43 AM
DC11   (UTC-04:00) Santiago 4/26/2017 11:34:44 AM
DHCP10 (UTC-04:00) Santiago 4/26/2017 11:34:44 AM
DHCP11 (UTC-04:00) Santiago 4/26/2017 11:34:45 AM
```

this is the line of output in my script:

```
Write-Host "$Server $TimeZone  $date_time"
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the 2-minute [tour]. 
Moreover, open [Help] and read at least [ask]. Then, [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually do something like this:

```
New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject -Property @{
            Server= $Server
            Timezone= $TimeZone
            DateTime= $DateTime}
```

You can then show that on screen or export to CSV or whatever works for you.

Answer (score 2):

or like this :

```
[pscustomobject]@{Server= $Server;Timezone= $TimeZone;DateTime= $DateTime}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks guys i followed your advice and  i was able to give format to my output

+10 for you guys!